# What are the spiritual benefits of worshipping goddess Gouri?

Tags: shiva, devi

As goddess Gouri is connected to feminine aspects of brain (emotions, love, devotion etc). Will worshipping goddess Gouri helps us to ( helps mean being lubricant or catalyst )  make us femininely strong, i.e emotionally strong? 
Also, As Lord Shiva is connected to intellect/masculinity, goddess Gouri is connected to mind (manas)/feminine so will it help to **control mind** as well?